# Writing a server-side language program to render web sites (HTML, etc..)

Tags: c++, web-services, server-side

Similar to technologies like ASP.NET, PHP, JSP and some other web languages which run on the server side are often called within a web pages code. For instance a web server may parse through a file hit

I don't have any difficulty writing server / client programs, only I am unsure where to tie in to web servers such that it will realize my own tag, run it through my software and output the resulting text to the requested file (most likely a web page.)

What does one need to do in order to accomplish this tie-in with a simple custom language?

The software is coded in C++.

Comment: What web servers are you using/do you want to support? Each has their own approach to extensions and external request handlers.

Comment: the simplest is cgi. you can go from there

Comment: @outis: We're using Windows Server 2003 w/IIS but I also frequently use Apache.

Comment: @Alf: We've got FastCGI which does work for the most part, but not really the intended integration level.

Comment: @Garet: then I think u should look at one of the existing frameworks. I did such a thing from scratch using PHP. But it was just a toy thing, for a childhood friend of mine who wanted a more modern web presence for his little at-home firm. For more professional work look into content management systems. There are a bunch of them. Cheers,

Comment: Well it isn't exactly my choice as to what to do. If I can manage to let their mini-developers script pages the way they are asking, then I'll get a bonus =P They want 'their own language that works like php but different' and it has to integrate at the same level. oh boy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement your own simple custom language you would need to do the following under Apache and something very similar under IIS.

For example for an Apache server to process PHP the following configuration is required.

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
ScriptAlias /php/ "/usr/local/php/bin/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
Action application/x-httpd-php /php/php
```

This directs the server to pass all calls to the server  with the file extension .php to the php processor and replaces and execute the tags in the file.

IIS has a similar mechanism which I think is configured through 'Handler Mappings'

I don't personally think that creating a custom tag language is the correct route to go.  You would be better served by writing a wrapper in either ASP or PHP to your C++ application. This would give you full access to the range of function in PHP or ASP that you will probably need e.g. Request parameter handling, etc.